# Replace input value with emoji unicode for HTML

Tags: jquery, regex, replace, emoji

I have the following **chat application**, and I want to **replace** any string containing `':)'` with `'&#1F600;'` so that it becomes an **emoji**.

What I have done so far doesn´t work. I believe my regex is correct.

The relevant snippet:

```
 if ($('#m').val().match(/(\:\))/g)) {
     $('#m').val() = $('#m').val().replace(/(\:\))/g, '&#1F600;')
 }
```

The context:

```
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
        <input id="m" autocomplete="off" />
        <button>Send</button>
    </form>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.4/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io(); // connect to the server
    $(function () {

         if ($('#m').val().match(/(\:\))/g)) {
            $('#m').val() = $('#m').val().replace(/(\:\))/g,'&#1F600;')
         }

        $('form').submit(function () {
            socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
            $('#m').val('');
            return false;
        });

        socket.on('chat message', function (msg) {
            $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
        });

    });

</script>
```

Comment: `$('#m').keyup(function (){
     value = $('#m').val().replace(/(\:\))/g, '&#1F600;');
     $('#m').val(value);
 });`

Comment: thank's it works at least, but it seems that the code '&#1F600; for the emoji does not turns into an emoji.

Comment: Maybe [`.replace(/:\)/g, '&#x1F600;')`](https://jsfiddle.net/qghyb5bt/2/)?

Comment: nope..it does't work

Comment: just use https://github.com/mervick/emojionearea